# add class library reference (framwork 4.6.1) to asp.net core in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-1.1

I have added class library developed in framework 4.6.1 in my asp.net core 1.1 application. I can access the classes and other objects of my class library in my asp.net core project. But when I run my project I runtime error. If I remove the classes and all referenced Object of class library from my code it work. Is there a solution.

Code:

```
  public IActionResult Inquiry([FromBody] MerchantDetailModel details)
            {
                string consumerKey = "-ASDFEEE";
                string keyAlias = "WeirdAlias";
                string keyPassword = "Gooddat";
//This is the class inside the class library
                TerminationMatchInquiry inquiry = new TerminationMatchInquiry(details);

//This where the runtime error comes
                var result = inquiry.RequestCall(consumerKey, keyAlias, keyPassword);
                return new JsonResult("Match");
            }

Error:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'MasterCard-Core, Version=1.4.0.26200, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

Comment: Before you rebuild/build your solution, reference the dll of the class and make sure 'Copy Local' in the properties (on the right) is set to true. That way, when you build/rebuild, it will copy the dll to your debug folder.

Comment: does not work..

Comment: When it 'fails' to rebuild, could you post here the error message it gives?

Comment: I have edited my question